# Decrypting a string using Fernet

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, fernet

I am trying a project that involves encrypting passwords using Fernet library. I have been able to enter, encrypt, and store passwords, but I keep getting the following error when I try to retrieve and decrypt the password.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:\Documents\python\practiceProjects\05 passwordManager\passwordManageV2.py", line 104, in modules  
pm.view()  

File "D:\Documents\python\practiceProjects\05 passwordManager\passwordManageV2.py", line 82, in view  
print (f'\nUser:  {user},  Password:   {***Fernet(self.key).decrypt(passw)***.decode()}\n')  
 
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 84, in decrypt  

timestamp, data = ***Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)***

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 118, in _get_unverified_token_data  

raise InvalidToken  

cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken<br/>
```

The code used to retrieve and decrypt the password is:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import glob
import os

class PasswordManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = None
        self.password_file = None
                
    def load_key (self):
        with open('key.key', 'rb') as f:
                self.key = f.read()
        
    def num_file_check (self):
        file = glob.glob('*.txt')
        
        self.password_file = file[0]
        
        if self.key == None:
            self.load_key ()


    def view (self):
        
        self.num_file_check ()
        
        with open(self.password_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                data = line 
                try:
                    user, passw = data.split(":")
                    print (f'\nUser:  {user},  Password:   {Fernet(self.key).decrypt(passw).decode()}\n')
                except ValueError:
                    continue

pm = PasswordManager ()
pm.view()
```

I tried adding 'rb' to `with open(self.password_file, 'r') as f:`, as suggested.  However, I received:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' at user, passw = data.split(":").*

The self.key is in the form b'*key*' while the only the key (minus the b' ') is stored in the key.key file.   Further, when I view the password file, I can see the password was encrypted before being written to the file

```
Site:b'gAAAAABl9KjKHh4MaltYyguafWmjwNjd35wbvfyMZMZEu-t3pabud_B7TDRIjVBaAWKkeZURYN0IGDsKD2XKkdtN2yycFrBlrw=='
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] that would make it easier for us to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: We need to see how the input files were generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input files weren't provided, but if the password file has a `Site` entry like shown, the input file was written incorrectly and should not have the `b''` around it which is the `str()` representation of a `bytes` object.

Below generates a fresh `key.key` and `passwords.txt` file containing the encryption key and a couple of username/password lines, respectively.  The OP's code is modified to read from these files correctly:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def generate_test_files():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()  # result is bytes object
    with open('key.key', 'wb') as file:  # so write in binary
        file.write(key)
    f = Fernet(key)

    # Write as UTF-8 to support all Unicode characters for user name.
    with open('passwords.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        for user, password in (('Marco', 'contraseña'), ('马克', '密码')):
            # Encrypt the UTF-8-encoded password.
            # Decode the bytes object as ASCII, which is a subset of UTF-8.
            # UTF-8 would work too, since the encryption is only ASCII bytes.
            # The resulting Unicode object can be written to the file.
            password = f.encrypt(password.encode()).decode('ascii')
            print(f'{user}:{password}', file=file)

class PasswordManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.load_key()
        self.password_file = 'passwords.txt'

    def load_key(self):
        with open('key.key', 'rb') as f:
                self.key = f.read()

    def view(self):
        with open(self.password_file, encoding='utf8') as f:
            for line in f:
                user, passw = line.split(':')  # no b'' now to mess it up
                # Encode str password to bytes and decrypt.
                # Decode to print without b''.
                print(f'User:     {user}\nPassword: {Fernet(self.key).decrypt(passw.encode()).decode()}\n')

generate_test_files()
pm = PasswordManager()
pm.view()
```

**Outputs:**

key.key (ASCII-only):

```
3DZpe5WlOPFj_EQnSAXTUbOGbQvf-JKV6lILx5JIvAo=
```

passwords.txt (UTF-8-encoded):

```
Marco:gAAAAABl9PuidgvythraNfo5_JhnbIltp4g54Ej5TVPXj5Ec0PVCZellsASafgnOcdCY4In77yjaBroKgDXiRWtSygSYzTuiPw==
马克:gAAAAABl9PujHyIYpvmzeo909kt6LFT6_I1ya098vFsoRCukX48WjoqWUniVOcB0jqZ5aOr1VAXYIr_p7Q80XCYBFo3RhEUVSA==
```

Terminal (subject to font support):

```
User:     Marco
Password: contraseña

User:     马克
Password: 密码
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're failing to read/write your files in binary mode? Here's a working example.

To write the key and encrypted data:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

data = "my deep dark secret"

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(data.encode())

with open("example.key", "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(key)

with open("example.data", "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(token)
```

To read the key and decrypt the data:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

with open("example.key", "rb") as fd:
    key = fd.read()

f = Fernet(key)

with open("example.data", "rb") as fd:
    token = fd.read()

data = f.decrypt(token)
print(data.decode())
```

---

Note that this code takes care of encoding the original string into its utf-8 representation, and then decoding that back into a Python string when we decrypt the data.